# NSDateFormatter produces null result Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, date

So I have this string date

```
"2017-07-25T11:02:00.000Z"
```

I want to format this date so that I can assign it to my date picker

Below is my code

```
    //Set the date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.userDefaultQuotationModel.dateTime];
   [self.quotationDatePicker setDate:dateFromString];
```

however, if I set the date format as @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ", it gives me the correct result based on the format. But afterwards, I can't assign this date to the date picker.

I set the date format as @"MMM d, yyyy" because I am looking for the the nearest format as Date Picker's

my Date picker format is Jul 25 2017. I get the date format from this following website

```
http://nsdateformatter.com/
```

The *dateFromString does not contain any value after the dateFromString function, which is nil

I have been searching regarding this topic but couldn't find any. What am I missing here? thank you

Comment: What is the class of `quotationDatePicker`?

Comment: What do you get when you NSLog the NSDate?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *strInputDateString = @"2017-07-25T11:02:00.000Z";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];

//Set new dateFormate
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:strInputDateString];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy"];

NSString *strOutputDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date1];
NSLog(@"%@",strInputDateString);
NSLog(@"%@",strOutputDateString);
```